# Update wordserver.conf

Tags: azerothcore

Been trying to know if there is an easy way to update the `worldserver.conf` when changes are committed to `worldserver.conf.dist`. Or it is necessary to do it manually always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automated way, however you can use the `diff` command to make it easy to spot the differences between your `worldserver.conf` and the new `worldserver.conf.dist`.

Assuming that you have those two files in the same folder, you can run:

```
diff worldserver.conf worldserver.conf.dist > worldserver.diff
```

this will generate a diff file `worldserver.diff` containing all the differences between `worldserver.conf.dist` and `worldserver.conf` so it will easy for you to spot what the new additions are and update your `worldserver.conf` accordingly.

When you're done you can of of course delete the `worldserver.diff`